# MongoDB Stitch trigger delay

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

Are there known delays with MongoDB Stitch triggers? I see a 1-2 minute gap between authentication events and trigger completion.

I have a simple [Authentication Trigger](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/authentication-triggers/) which executes on **Create**. In other words, the trigger fires when a new user is added.

The trigger calls the function below to add the new user to a temporary collection.

```
exports = async function(authEvent) {
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const newUsers = mongodb.db("DATABASE").collection("newUsers");

  const { user, time } = authEvent;
  const newUser = { ...user, eventLog: [ { "created": time } ], access: [{"status": "pending"}] };
  await newUsers.insertOne(newUser);
}
```

The results are shown below. The **authEvent** records user creation time as *11:40*. However, the new document isn't inserted until *11:42*.

[image: inserted record]

What's the reason for the delay?

Server Version: cloud-2.26.4UI Version: 3.25.3JS SDK Version: 3.4.0
Plan: M0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this delay was placement of the *Atlas* deployment in **one region** and the *Stitch* deployment in **a different region**.

According to the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/admin/deployment-models-and-regions/#global-deployment):

> Write operations to a linked MongoDB cluster are handled within a single region that you specify when you [create your application](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/procedures/create-stitch-app/).